# Can't use header-redirect from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect, header

I'm trying to make my PHP file redirect to an HTML file.

My website is constructed this way:

HTML ==> js seperate file (using angular) ===> PHP file

Then the php calls header function- but instead of redirecting, it prints the code of the HTML page I'm trying to open.

I haven't echoed anything before the calling the header function (though I've used one header in the beginning of the PHP file for Access Control).

I've also tried echo the "meta http equiv" tag with the wanted URL, but it just printed the tag.

Maybe it's because I'm using seperate files for php, js and HTML ?

Thanks!

Here's my PHP code:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
//header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = '';

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, "myDB");
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$client_data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($client_data);
$sql = "SELECT Password FROM users WHERE Name=\"". $json->username ."\"";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows >0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if (password_verify($json->password ,$row["Password"])) {
            header ('location: http://localhost/KickStartProject/views/register.html');
        } else {
            echo "Password didn't match.....";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: HTML page is making ajax request to this page?

Comment: yes. using:  $http.post

Comment: I don't think an ajax request will redirect a user, don't work in js much though so maybe it would? I'd try returning 1 or 0; 1 for valid. If `1` then use window.location (i think) to direct user back on the html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @chris85 pointed out in his comment, ajax requests doesn't affect current document's location. You should make redirection like this:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
...
if (!$conn) {
    die(json_encode(["status"=>"err", "msg" => "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()]));
}
...
    if(password_verify ($json->password ,$row["Password"]) ){

        die(json_encode(["status"=>"ok", "redirect" => "/KickStartProject/views/register.html"]));
    }else{
        die(json_encode(["status"=>"err", "msg" => "Password didn't match....."]));
    }
...
```

And in yours javascript:

```
...
$.getJSON('/url-to-php', {...})
 .success(function(response) {
     if (response.status != "ok")
         alert(response.msg);
     else
         document.location.href = response.redirect;
 });
...
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks. I'm trying to implement it with angular using $http (I'm not using JQuery).

I'll be back after I'm done.

Comment: Works like magic. 
I've been looking for this for some time now... you have no idea how much you've helped!
Thanks!! :)